# Problem – QGIS 2.2 - Values under Color Rendering saved in style not applied when applying the loaded style?

Tags: style, color, qml, qgis-2.2

I have saved two variants of the same color-scheme by putting in different values under “color rendering” in the lower part of the screen. It’s a singleband pseudocolor scheme.

Now when I load each of the styles as qml-File while in the Properties-Menu of my DEM it instantly shows me the desired colors in the canvas. I can also see the slight difference between the two variants in the canvas resulting from the different “brightness” values in my two styles.

In this "Preview Mode" everything is great.
But the Moment I click on "Apply" or "OK" when I want to finally apply one of the two versions it switches back to a state as if no changes under color rendering have been made.

So is this a bug? When first loading the style it shows the correct adjustments (so it must be stored somewhere inside the qml file) but when clicking "Apply" all Information under color rendering is ignored?

Or am I doing sth wrong?

When I open the properties windows again on the quite dully colored DEM after trying to apply my style and then manually reenter my desired value under "color rendering" and click "Apply" it thens also applies the desired tweaks.

Edit:
With a Singleband Grey Style it works. I have two variants with different values under "color rendering" and when loading and applying everything looks correctly.

Comment: Please edit your tags to include what software you're using, I can't help if I don't know what program you're talking about.

Comment: Edited it, sorry, completely forgot. Using QGIS 2.2.